# Should a backbone.js model delegate save to another model?

Tags: architecture, backbone.js

Considering how to model the interaction of the user with a set of customizable items, it seems this is a pretty common case. I wonder if there is a conventional architecture to represent this with backbone. 
[image: Class dependency example]

This diagram depicts the relationships between a couple of views and models that we are designing. The ItemNavigator View allows the user to view all the UserItems in his collection. Each UserItem stores the user-customized properties of one (shared) Item. The user views the Item in the ItemEditor View and customizes its properties. The question is, does it make sense for the Item.save() method to pass the custom properties to the UserItem model to save?

An example Item would be a shirt style that allows selection of size and color. The UserItem would refer to the shirt style (Item at "/items/shirts/polo") and store {color: "red", size: "L"}.

This approach seems interesting partly because the Item resources will be cacheable and common to all users.

Comment: are `UserItem` models extended from the `ItemState` model?

Comment: The architecture anticipates that UserItems will be a Collection of ItemState Models. It could be appropriate for Item to extend ItemState, but we hadn't really considered that, since we'd been thinking that an Item exists independent of any state.

Comment: What is the function of ItemState? You call it a constant resource, but I'm trying to understand whether it is a separate object or is it a hash of varying fields representing custom properties. Also, is an Item the same as a UserItem? Also, a brief description of the system and what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Tried to simplify the naming and provide a (perhaps overly?) simple example.